# How can I save reference Id In Jmeter? and generate it new in each iteration

Tags: testing, cookies, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am doing load testing on ticket purchase website.

in that website there are 2 pages
Page 1: where there are list of tickets and one you add ticket in that cart than it shows 'checkout' button.
Page 2: By click on checkout it will redirect on other page, and user have to fill other details of buyer (email and name) and complete the order.

when user redirect from page 1 to page 2 than it create one reference id. so, if I want to test this whole process with 50 users than 50 reference if will be created.

I need help to generate that reference id for each user.
I tried with regular expression extractor and Http cookie manager but refrence id is not generated.

Need Help!

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing how does this "reference Id" (whatever it is) look like in the response.

- Normally [you shouldn't be using regular expressions for getting data from HTML pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8592047), it might be a better idea to consider using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8592047)
- If this "reference Id" comes as a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) - a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) will automatically handle it. If you need to use a cookie value elsewhere - you can tell the Cookie Manager to store cookies into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) by setting `CookieManager.save.cookies` property to `true`